# How to acces txt file in netbeans build jar file?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

So currently my netbeans project folders looks like this:

- Block_Breaker <--Project

  - build
  - dist

    - Block_Breaker.jar
  - nbproject
  - src

    - packageONE
    - packageTWO

      - data.txt
  - manifest.mf
  - applet.policy
  - build.xml

I want to know how can i acces a data.txt file in packageTWO(when i run Block_Breaker through a jar file and not netbeans). Normally if run through netbeans the following code will work:

```
FileWriter x=new FileWriter("src/packageTWO/data.txt");

PrintWriter pr=new PrintWriter(x);
```

But if i run a jar file that netbeans created it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

You can't write to that file once it is packaged into a jar file.

Yet reading is still possible using one of the following:

```
<YourClass>.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("packageTWO/data.txt");
// or
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/packageTWO/data.txt");
```

witch gives you an [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) witch you can use to retrieve the content of the file.

If you are required to wite to that file then the simplest way is not to pack it into the jar but have it standalone some where on the filesystem.

More infos about `getResourceAstream` in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Yeah i should have known that myself sorry for being such a dumbass.

Comment: @user1952989 heh, don't be so harsh on yourself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `.jar` file does not include a folder named `src/`

Please use `ClassLoader.getResource` to load resources.